# content query web part to display content from another page

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a need to render content from another page using a content query web part. I've found several examples on how to accomplish custom fields using common-view-fields but nothing specific on how to query page content from another page.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Content Query Webpart" is typically used for aggregation - you have a lot of pages in your portal and you want to create a page which summarizes the headlines or some other properties that every item in your portal has.

In your scenario, as far as I understand, you have a page in your portal and you want to create another page, which displays the same content. In this case the "[List form webpart](http://kalsing.blogspot.com/2006/11/create-custom-list-form-for-sharepoint.html)"  or a "[data view webpart](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/12/data-view-web-part-the-basics-insert-a-dvwp-on-your-page/)" would sound more reasonable.

Comment: thanks. was exactly what I want to do. will check those two parts out.